# Illegal Variable Name/Number

Tags: php, sql, oracle10g

I have a field called `database_work_location` in the following code:

```
$database_work_location =& new Select_Database_Work_Location();
$database_work_location->setSelected($in['database_work_location']);
$form->addElement('database_work_location', $database_work_location );
```

And I display it on the form using the following code:

```
<p>
Database Location:<br />
<?= $form->render('database_work_location'); ?>
</p>
```

So far that works and I am able to select a location without any problems at all.

Finally, I am sending it to the database using the following code:

```
case 'DATABASE':

$args[] = array('database_work_location', $in['database_work_location']);

$DB->query("
    INSERT INTO request_database
    (
        database_work_location
    )
    VALUES (
        :database_work_location
    )
    "
    ,$args
    );

    break;
```

However, I am getting the following error when I try to submit the form, and I have no clue why.

```
SQL Error: 1036 - ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
[query]

INSERT INTO request_database
(
database_work_location
)
VALUES (
:database_work_location
)

[binds] request_cn => [9867520000] length=[] created_by => [someone] length=[] database_work_location => [theplace] length=[]
```

So, if the binds are coming through correctly, (it recognizes the selected location), why is it telling me it's an illegal variable?

In the database table, the column `database_work_location` is a varchar2 of size 100, I honestly can't see the issue.

Comment: any reaction ? Are you here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use the PDOStatement like this :

```
case 'DATABASE':

$stm = $DB->prepare('INSERT INTO request_database(database_work_location)
VALUES (:database_work_location)');

$stm->bindParam(':database_work_location', $in['database_work_location']);

$stm->execute();

break;
```

Comment: I will try this tomorrow morning and accept if it works, I appreciate you trying, sorry I haven't been on recently :)

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented your code, now it might be work well

```
case 'DATABASE':

$args[] = array('database_work_location', $in['database_work_location']);

$DB->query("
    INSERT INTO request_database
    (
        database_work_location
    )
    VALUES (
        database_work_location
    )
    "
    ,$args
    );

    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
case 'DATABASE':

$args = array('database_work_location', $in['database_work_location']);

$DB->query("
    INSERT INTO request_database
    (
        database_work_location
    )
    VALUES (
        database_work_location
    )
    "
    ,$args
    );

    break;
```

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you doesn't want to use the solution suggested by Rida (that's the better way), I think that your error was to use a wrong name, the driver can't distinguish from column name to data.

Try this:

```
$args[] = array('database_work_location_data', $in['database_work_location']);

$DB->query("
    INSERT INTO request_database
    (
        database_work_location
    )
    VALUES (
        :database_work_location_data
    )
    "
    ,$args
    );

    break;
```

If I'm not clear, ask me.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just?

```
case 'DATABASE':

    $query = 'INSERT INTO request_database(database_work_location)
    VALUES ('. $in['database_work_location'] .')';

    $stm = $DB->prepare($query);

    $stm->execute();

    break;
```

Comment: Because you will loose the prepared statement advantage that's performence.

Comment: This will create a SQL injection attack!

Comment: Not if you escape the array value(s)